# exclude bower package files/folders for asp.net core web application

Tags: asp.net-core, bower

For an ASP.NET core web application (use Visual Studio 2017), when using bower to install a package(eg: alertifyJS), bower download all the files related to alertifyJS under wwwroot/lib folder, like build, docpad, src and some other files.

When publish/deploy the project (I choose to publish to file system), folders like src, docpad and some other files, are useless, but still get published (copied).

Is there a way to exclude some of the files/folders under wwwroot/lib from being published, so that I don't need to remove the files manually?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question in case someone has the same issue/question.

For the unused folders, choose to "excluded from project", for the unused files, change the build action from "default (content)" to "None".

I am not sure this is the right way to do it, but it works.